# ¿Como agregar texto de validación a un input de formulario con Renderer y ElementRef en Angular4?

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Estoy intentando agregar mensajes de validación en Angular 4 obtenidos desde la Api en mi formulario, he estado checando que puedo utilizar Renderer2 y ElementRef pero no encuentro como buscar el input por Id y agregar el mensaje debajo de él.

En AngularJs era posible agregar un mensaje en la etiqueta "P" dinámicamente de la siguiente forma:

`angular.element('#'+key).parent().find("p").html(msg.ErrorMessage);`

El código de mi formulario es el siguiente:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="serie">Serie</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="serie"
 [(ngModel)]="serie" #serie="ngModel" required />
   <p class="help-block">
     // Insertar mensaje aquí
   </p>
</div>
```

Y el objeto que yo recibo de la Api puede ser de la siguiente forma:

```
[{ element: 'serie', message: 'La serie ya ha sido agregada anteriormente.'}]
```

Artículo de referencia de uso de Renderer2 y ElementRef
[Using Renderer2 in Angular](https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/).

¿Es posible agregar un mensaje de forma dinámica teniendo el Id del input y el mensaje que se va a agregar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y no es más sencillo añadir el div en tu template y sólo generarlo cuando hace falta?

Pones algo así en tu template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="serie">Serie</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="serie" [(ngModel)]="serie" #serie="ngModel" required />
    <p *ngIf="isValid('serie')" class="help-block">
        // Insertar mensaje aquí
    </p>
</div>
```

Y añades una función isValid( a tu componente formulario donde compruebas si el valor del input es correcto o no.

Comment: Si yo recibo de la Api los campos que tienen error, de esa forma guardaría un arreglo con los datos y al validar que si se regresó un mensaje de error podría mostrar ese mensaje. Pero es conveniente hacer eso para cada campo de cada formulario?

Comment: Yo lo hago así, incluso añado clases al div form-group para que se marque el input con borde rojo cuando no es válido

Comment: Al final lo dejé como me comentas, solo que no lo valido con ngIf, si el servidor me regresó errores los agrego a un arreglo de ese campo y en el template recorro los errores por si hay más de un mensaje y también agrego la clase has-error para que lo muestre como error, gracias!